# Docker - under Windows 10 Pro - Need to map volumes and have them work, not quietly fail

Tags: mongodb, docker

I ran various containers on Two different Windows 10 Pro machines, and thought that I had the data drives mapped correctly, but now I'm finding out that it isn't writing the data there at all.  One example was Mongo db, where I mapped /mongodb/database:/data/db     I upgraded docker, and when it restarted mongodb.. POOF! no data, I thought that was weird and looked in /mongodb/database and the directory is empty.  Thankfully, the app is still in the development phase, and not critical that the data was lost...

the line from the docker compose file:

```
   volumes:
      - /mongodb/database:/data/db
```

Different machine:
I installed Gogs/gogs image, mapping the data:

```
docker run --name=Gogs-Git -p 10022:22 -p 10080:3000 -v /var/gogs:/Docker/Gogs-GitServer/Data gogs/gogs
```

Seemed to work perfectly, so I was thinking everything was fine, I pushed a Repo up to it.. and today, I looked at \Docker\Gogs-gitserver\data and no files... so where did it write the data?

I also installed TeamCity, mapping that data.. nope, it has no logs, no data...

This feature seems to just not work at all.  I found a reference from 2016 saying I need to look at the 'shared' tab (below general),and check C: to be shared, but well, no, that isn't a tab, so it isn't that.

There is no way someone would write a system that just quietly wrote the data some other place, or didn't bother actually mapping it without giving an error - that would be nuts.

So, there must be some other explanation...  One of the machines has Hyper-V enabled in the BIOS, the other one doesn't even support it as far as I know.

I think some of the images are Linux, and some are Windows (TeamCity I'm pretty sure is)

OK, this is interesting... If I look at the volumes, and enter one that is in use, I get this:
[image: Volumes]

The Target looks about like the right path, but I'm not sure about the /backup and the /data on the last two lines, if these are supposed to be directories under that, they don't exist, but if I click on the data tab, I can see the data, it is in Docker, hidden and not shared, in spite of there being a 'target' that points at the right directory... how to I get it to start writing this data correctly to that folder??

Answer (score 0):

I've not confirmed this yet with the above configuration, but I found that for other containers, I needed to specify the path as 'c:/data/MongoDb/Database' when I created the container using that as the path, it worked and I have data there now.  I just need to go back and fix all these VMs so they have their data correctly...